# How to set the minimum number of words written in a text box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to set a minimum number of text that is written in a text box.

Normally we use the `min` property of html. But I don't want it.

Can anybody help me with the JavaScript code which check the number of text written in a text box and if it is lesser than 7 and greater than 21 an alert box would be shown. Or else it wont

```
<input type="text" id="txt">
<input type="button" onClick="myFunction()">
```

Js

```
function myFunction() {
   .....
}
```

I know only this much.
Please help

Comment: "But I don't want it." Why not?

Comment: Have you tried anything ? How about `.length` property..?

Comment: Kevin bro it wont give any alert or any warning if we type less numbers

Comment: Number of characters or number of words?

Comment: No matter whether Number of characters or number of words. Just need a answer

Comment: Well, maybe that's for a good reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function myFunction() {
 if ($('#txt').val().length < 21 && $('#txt').val().length > 7) alert("yez");
}

$('button').on('click', function() {
  myFunction()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt">
<button>click</button>
```

this should work - it checks the length of the content in your `#txt` HTML element. If its greater than 7 and smaller than 21 it will alert `yez`

Comment: Thank you for the answer bro

Answer (score 3):

You can use pattern attribute of HTML5

```
This will set minimum characters required to 1 and max characters required 
to 15

<input type="text" id="txt" pattern="[a-z]{1,15}>
```

Answer (score 1):

i added snippet which is counting only number of real 'words' empty spaces are omitted.

```js
function wordCount(text) {
  totalCount = 0;
  words = text.split(' ')
  words.forEach(function(word) {
    if (word.length > 0) {
      totalCount++;
    }
  })
  
  return totalCount;
}

window.myFunction = function() {
 textarea = document.getElementById('txt');
 words = wordCount(textarea.value);
 if(words < 7 || words > 21) {
   alert('Wrong number of words');
 }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt">
<input type="button" onClick="myFunction()" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger an event on `blur` that means, when the text box loses focus

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#text-box').blur(function(){
     var value = $('#text-box').val();
        if(value.length < 7 || value.length > 21){
         alert("Invalid length");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text-box">
```

Answer (score 1):

function validate(){

```
x=document.myForm
input=x.myInput.value
if (input.length>5){
    alert("The field cannot contain more than 5 characters!")
    return false
}else {
    return true
}
```

}